# error while trying to get the int from a string

Tags: c++, string, int

I want to get the int from the string, without using the int type directly to get advantages from getline() but somehow I get an error if the input is not an actual int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    string word = {0};

    cout << "Enter the number 5 : ";

    getline(cin, word);

    int i_word = stoi(word);

    cout << "Your answer : " << i_word << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When the user input is 5 (or any other int) the output is :

```
Enter the number 5 : 5
Your answer : 5
```

When the user input is either ENTER or any other letter, word, etc... :

```
Enter the number 5 : e
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Comment: Read up on exception handling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called exception handling:

```
try
{
    int i_word = stoi(word);

    cout << "Your answer : " << i_word << endl;
} 
catch (const std::invalid_argument& e)
{
    cout << "Invalid answer : " << word << endl;
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& e)
{
    cout << "Invalid answer : " << word << endl;
}
```

Comment: Neat, exactly what I needed. I didn't know there was exception handling mecanism in c++, I'm trying to learn on my own. Thanks a lot for your quick&clear answer.

Comment: @Gradiuss Perhaps learning from a book would be a better option.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but for now I'm kind of testing what suits me best between C and C++ but I find C++ handy and easy to learn. But thanks for the advice @user2079303

Comment: I would prefer C++: here is great tutorial http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: It also needs `catch(std::out_of_range& e)`

Comment: Is there something like else catch ?

Comment: @Gradiuss what do you mean?

Comment: You said it also needs to catch if out of range right so I just to add another catch() or is there something like if () else if () else () ?

Comment: It's clearly explained in the tutorial I posted: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/ (updated answer)